# Checking if root nodes and child nodes in a TreeView are the same

Tags: c#, treeview, duplicates, nodes

So I have a TreeView and am checking for duplicates. If I add a node to the tree and then try to add the same node, my code won't let that happen. Which is what I want. But now I need to check the child nodes, so if the root nodes are the same but if the first child of the root node is different then the one being added, I want to add those child nodes under that root node that's already there. I have tried:

```
if(node.Text == root.text && node.FirstNode.Text == root.FirstNode.Text) 
      nodes.Remove(node);
```

But that gives me a null exception on root.FirstNode.Text and I'm not sure why it is getting null when node.FirstNode.Text shows the child node.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It means whatever node you've assigned to `root` has no children (hence `root.FirstNode` is null). `node.FirstNode` can still show it's first child node if whichever node you assigned to that one is different from the one assigned to `root`.

The important thing here is that just because they have the same text, doesn't mean they are the same node. Judging by the code provided, they are referring to different object (with different collections of child nodes, or lack of)

I'm imagining something like the following (not actual code):

```
|- SomeNode           //Refers to "root" in your code. Note lack of child
|- SomeNode           //Refers to "node". Note same text as "root"
  |- ChildNode        //Would refer to node.FirstChild
```

So you'll get nodes with the same text, but totally different layouts.

Comment: Well the root node(ARXXX) has folders in it, and when I add that node to the Tree, the childs it shows the first folder and its files. But when I add a different folder from that same node to the tree. It wacks the folder thats already on the tree. I want to add the new folder under the previous folder because they are from the same root node.

Comment: RootNode - ChildNodeFolder - ItemsInFolder. Node is the new folder thats being added to the tree. So node would have the same RootNode but a different ChildNodeFolder name.

Comment: So ChildNodeFolder is a child node to RootNode and ItemsInFolder is a child node to ChildNodeFolder?

Comment: Yea, ItemsInFolder are just the documents inside that ChildNodeFolder. Its not really important but I added it anyway

Comment: I think you really have 2 questions here.. Why are you getting the exception (which I've answered) and how do you go about adding nodes to the correct parent nodes?

Comment: I guess, idk its hard to explain. I have a ticket(RootNode) with a bunch of folders(ChildNodeFolders) so when i open up the RootNode in the form and click on the first folder. that shows up in the view under the RootNode. But when i go back to that ticket and click on another folder, it reloads the treeview under the RootNode to that ChildFolder. But I want that first folder to stay there as well as the new one I just selected.

Answer (score 0):

If they are two nodes of the same TreeView, u can use the TreeNode.FullPath property:

After getting the new node full path, u navigate the treenode into the final path and if there is another node with the same name u delete the first added.
It was not really clear from the code provided, but i think u can use this strategy.

Anyway, FullPath documentation is in the following link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.fullpath(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope it helped!

EDIT: 
sorry, a full day working i'm sleeping, as they said FullPath is a property, edited

Comment: TreeNode.FullPath is a property, not a method